# Which Windows services and startup programs can I disable/modify to optimize performance/security?

Tags: windows, security, performance, internet, performance-tuning

Windows 7 SP1:

I use this stand-alone (no LAN) computer at home exclusively to browse the internet, nothing else!.. I have another computer I use for development and testing which I never connect to the internet. What should I do to improve performance and security on both machines?